# Как узнать какие ветки были влиты в определенную ветку

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch

Как узнать какие ветки были влиты в ветку зная хэш коммита source и target веток

Comment: `git log --oneline branch-name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно вот так:

```
git log --oneline --merges --ancestry-path <hash_first>..<hash_last>
```

Где,

- oneline - формат вывода
- merges - только влитые коммиты, у которы
- ancestry-path - выводить только коммиты между hash_first и hash_last
- hash_first - первый коммит (по времени)
- hash_last - последний коммит (по времени)

На выводе будет список коммитов слияния. Также можно определить из какой ветки  пришел коммит (тут может быть неточность, по сути показывает каким веткам принадлежит этот коммит).

```
git branch --contains <merge_commit>
```

Где merge_commit - вывод предыдущей команды

Answer (score 1):

в общем случае — никак.

ведь «ветка» в программе *git* — это не набор (как-то «помеченных») коммитов, а всего-лишь указатель на коммит. к тому же «плавающий»: его положение смещается по мере поступления коммитов.

более того: на один и тот же коммит может указывать любое количество указателей.

ещё более того: при слиянии можно не пользоваться вообще ни одним указателем, а использовать хэш нужного коммита.

---

но в реально встречающихся в жизни ситуациях с определённой долей достоверности некие эмпирические выводы по поводу того «что там с чем сливалось» всё-таки можно сделать. например, воспользовавшись командой `log` программы *git*:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all
```

или какой-нибудь программой-визаулизатором истории коммитов с графическим интерфейсом.

Comment: а можно узнать коммиты между двумя коммитами?

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос